# rsync creates wrong backup directory names with a middle dot (·)

Tags: rsync

Under Windows, I use *rsync* to periodically clone some directory to `${LATEST_BACKUP_DIR}`. I also use the `--backup-dir="${OLD_BACKUP_DIR}"` option to keep backups of files' old versions that have changed since the last clone.

After running this *rsync* command, I noticed that old files are not put in `${OLD_BACKUP_DIR}`, but instead are put into a weirdly-named directory inside `${LATEST_BACKUP_DIR}`.

With *weirdly-named directory* I mean a directory that renders in *Windows Explorer* similar to the Unicode *MIDDLE DOT* (`·`). When copy-pasting this directory's name, it gives character `` (hexadecimal `ef 80 a2` ... `ï€¢`).

I have also noticed that with other `${OLD_BACKUP_DIR}` values, rsync creates directories such as

`· ..`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue. Running (updated) rsync from a mac between an afp and smb volume.

Answer (score 0):

I use *rsync* in a Windows7 Cygwin environment.

It turns out that (at least in my environment) *rsync* does not like the padding double quotes in `--backup-dir="${OLD_BACKUP_DIR}"`.

When I run rsync without the padding double quotes, i.e. `--backup-dir=${OLD_BACKUP_DIR}`, everything works fine (... as long as `${OLD_BACKUP_DIR}` does not include space characters).

Comment: That is odd; the _shell_ is supposed to strip those away, without rsync ever seeing them.

Comment: extra goodie: that rsync command is wrapped in an *expect* script